# WSDL function is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I have created sample soap server and client in zend framework controller,also I have discover wsdl url with autodiscovery in zend framework.
code is:

```
public function indexAction() {

    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $wsdl = 'http://localhost:7000/client/client/index?wsdl';

    if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
        try {
            $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
            //$autodiscover->setUri($wsdl);
            $autodiscover->setClass('Soapwsdl');
            $autodiscover->handle();
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            print_r($e->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
    } elseif (isset($_GET['server'])) {
        try {
            $soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($wsdl);
            $soap->setClass('Soapwsdl');
            $soap->handle();
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            $client = new Zend_Soap_Client($wsdl);

            $result = $client->math_add(10, 20);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            exit;
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

when I call wsdl url in browser first time then wsdl file generate successfully but when I refresh same again then page is loading and nothing happen.Same thing when I call populate with getFunction() with soap client object it gives me list of all function but when I call method to run with client object my page is loading not.

Anyone have solution?